# vuejs computed property for loop wont increment

Tags: for-loop, vue.js, filter, computed-properties

I have the following elements in my data property

```
 templateArray: [{"id":"7","itemId":"17520","itemName":"Arrow Bounce","thumbName":"ARROWBOUNCE","dateAdded":"2016-05-20 16:33:42","renderTime":"30","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2016\/ArrowBounce-Scott\/arrowBounce.aep","stillImageLocation":"2.66","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":["LensFlare"]},{"id":"11","itemId":"38752","itemName":"Jitter Zoom Flash","thumbName":"JITTERZOOMFLASH","dateAdded":"2016-05-23 13:49:03","renderTime":"45","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2016\/JitterZoomFlash-Scott\/JitterZoomFlash.aep","stillImageLocation":"2.66","categoryArray":["Sports"],"keywordArray":["Snow","Sparkles"]},{"id":"12","itemId":"12737","itemName":"Cloth Drop","thumbName":"CLOTHDROP","dateAdded":"2016-05-23 14:11:42","renderTime":"30","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2016\/ClothDrop-Scott\/cloth drop.aep","stillImageLocation":"2.66","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"15","itemId":"73076","itemName":"Colorful Trans","thumbName":"COLORFULIMAGETRANS","dateAdded":"2016-05-27 10:16:56","renderTime":"30","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2016\/ColorfulImageTrans-Scott\/ColorfulImageTrans.aep","stillImageLocation":"12.90","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":["Water","Sparkles"]},{"id":"16","itemId":"18488","itemName":"Convex &frac12; Circle","thumbName":"CONVEXHALFCIRCLE","dateAdded":"2016-05-27 10:38:20","renderTime":"30","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2016\/convexHalfCircle-Scott\/convex half circle.aep","stillImageLocation":"2.66","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"17","itemId":"67039","itemName":"Flag Swap","thumbName":"FLAGBACKSWAP","dateAdded":"2016-06-01 15:34:22","renderTime":"30","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2016\/FlagBackSwap-Scott\/FlagBackSwap.aep","stillImageLocation":"5.83","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"31","itemId":"70006","itemName":"Flag Raise","thumbName":"FLAGRAISE","dateAdded":"2016-06-03 11:13:37","renderTime":"60","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2016\/FlagRaise-Scott\/flag.aep","stillImageLocation":"2.66","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"32","itemId":"58759","itemName":"Logo Dust Poof","thumbName":"LOGODUSTPOOF","dateAdded":"2016-06-03 11:25:34","renderTime":"30","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2016\/LogoDustPoof-Scott\/LogoDustPoof.aep","stillImageLocation":"6.23","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"33","itemId":"58967","itemName":"Flag Wave (Loop)","thumbName":"FLAGWAVE","dateAdded":"2016-06-03 11:35:49","renderTime":"75","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2016\/FlagWave-Scott\/FlagWave.aep","stillImageLocation":"2.66","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"34","itemId":"65288","itemName":"Logo Splash One","thumbName":"LOGOSPLASHONE","dateAdded":"2016-06-03 15:34:19","renderTime":"45","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2016\/LogoSplashOne-Scott\/LogoSplashOne.aep","stillImageLocation":"2.70","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"35","itemId":"91246","itemName":"Metal Sparks","thumbName":"METALSPARKS","dateAdded":"2016-06-06 10:58:29","renderTime":"60","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2016\/MetalSparks-Scott\/MetalSparks.aep","stillImageLocation":"4.63","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"36","itemId":"57489","itemName":"Middle Stripe","thumbName":"MIDDLESTRIPEABA","dateAdded":"2016-06-06 12:25:41","renderTime":"60","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2016\/MiddleStripe-Scott\/middleStripeABA.aep","stillImageLocation":"6.80","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"37","itemId":"38402","itemName":"Water One","thumbName":"WATERONE","dateAdded":"2016-06-07 09:10:32","renderTime":"60","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2016\/waterOne-Scott\/waterOne.aep","stillImageLocation":"8.83","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"39","itemId":"81031","itemName":"Oval Text Flip","thumbName":"OVALTEXTFLIP","dateAdded":"2016-05-07 09:10:32","renderTime":"150","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2016\/OvalTextFlip-Scott\/OvalTextFlip.aep","stillImageLocation":"2.66","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"40","itemId":"55143","itemName":"Close Up Text","thumbName":"CLOSEUPTEXT","dateAdded":"2016-07-05 09:10:32","renderTime":"85","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2016\/CloseUpText-Scott\/CloseUpText\/CloseUpText.aep","stillImageLocation":"9.03","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"41","itemId":"54335","itemName":"Electric Text Spin","thumbName":"ELECTRICTEXTSPIN","dateAdded":"2016-07-13 09:10:32","renderTime":"60","tested":"1","projectPath":"O:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2016\/ElectricTextSpin-Scott\/ElectricTextSpin\/ElectricTextSpin.aep","stillImageLocation":"1.47","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"42","itemId":"23761","itemName":"Digital Glitch","thumbName":"DIGITALGLITCH","dateAdded":"2016-09-19 09:10:32","renderTime":"60","tested":"1","projectPath":"O:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2016\/DigitalGlitch-Scott\/DigitalGlitch.aep","stillImageLocation":"3.43","categoryArray":["Retail"],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"43","itemId":"56465","itemName":"Takeover","thumbName":"TAKEOVER","dateAdded":"2016-09-30 14:10:32","renderTime":"80","tested":"1","projectPath":"O:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2016\/TakeOver-Scott\/TakeoverProject\/takeoverproject.aep","stillImageLocation":"2.66","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"44","itemId":"17127","itemName":"Fire One","thumbName":"FIREONE","dateAdded":"2016-11-04 14:10:32","renderTime":"25","tested":"1","projectPath":"O:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2016\/FireOne-Scott\/FireOne.aep","stillImageLocation":"2.66","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"53","itemId":"61617","itemName":"City Spin","thumbName":"CITYSPIN","dateAdded":"2016-11-09 14:17:15","renderTime":"45","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2016\/CitySpin-Scott\/cityspin.aep","stillImageLocation":"8.933","categoryArray":["Church"],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"56","itemId":"15528","itemName":"Magic Colors","thumbName":"MAGICCOLORS","dateAdded":"2016-11-10 13:10:26","renderTime":"30","tested":"1","projectPath":"O:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2016\/MagicColors-Scott\/MagicColors.aep","stillImageLocation":"3.966","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"61","itemId":"59239","itemName":"Quick and Simple","thumbName":"QUICKNSIMPLE","dateAdded":"2016-11-14 11:42:09","renderTime":"15","tested":"1","projectPath":"O:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2016\/QuickNSimple-Scott\/QuickNSimple.aep","stillImageLocation":"2.033","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"62","itemId":"82460","itemName":"Fast Blast","thumbName":"FASTBLAST","dateAdded":"2016-11-22 10:24:48","renderTime":"30","tested":"1","projectPath":"O:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2016\/FastBlast-Scott\/FastBlast.aep","stillImageLocation":"9.666","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"63","itemId":"83530","itemName":"Tunnel Spin","thumbName":"TUNNELSPIN","dateAdded":"2016-12-02 13:09:06","renderTime":"20","tested":"1","projectPath":"O:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2016\/tunnelSpin-Scott\/tunnelSpin.aep","stillImageLocation":"2.9","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"64","itemId":"94148","itemName":"Sparkle Splash","thumbName":"SPARKLESPLASH","dateAdded":"2016-12-20 11:23:26","renderTime":"45","tested":"1","projectPath":"O:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2016\/SparkleSplash-Scott\/SparkleSplash.aep","stillImageLocation":"6.1","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"69","itemId":"98640","itemName":"Gold Bling","thumbName":"GOLDBLING","dateAdded":"2017-01-10 08:16:41","renderTime":"30","tested":"1","projectPath":"O:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2017\/GoldBling-Joe\/GoldBling.aep","stillImageLocation":"2.66","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"72","itemId":"94169","itemName":"Top Racer","thumbName":"TOPRACER","dateAdded":"2017-02-15 09:46:14","renderTime":"30","tested":"1","projectPath":"O:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2017\/TopRacer-Scott\/TopRacer.aep","stillImageLocation":"7.833","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"73","itemId":"55871","itemName":"Desert Sand","thumbName":"DESERTSAND","dateAdded":"2017-02-15 14:04:49","renderTime":"45","tested":"1","projectPath":"O:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2017\/DesertSand-Scott\/DesertSand.aep","stillImageLocation":"10.46","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"76","itemId":"18897","itemName":"Electric Storm","thumbName":"ELECTRICSTORM","dateAdded":"2017-02-23 12:43:08","renderTime":"45","tested":"1","projectPath":"O:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2017\/ElectricStorm-Scott\/ElectricStorm.aep","stillImageLocation":"4.333","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"78","itemId":"24052","itemName":"Court Smash","thumbName":"COURTSMASH","dateAdded":"2016-06-03 12:03:48","renderTime":"90","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2017\/CourtSmash-Scott\/CourtSmash.aep","stillImageLocation":"5.933","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"81","itemId":"43553","itemName":"Tile Flip","thumbName":"TILEFLIP","dateAdded":"2017-04-25 16:40:41","renderTime":"60","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2017\/TileFlip-Chris\/TileFlip_Final\/TileFlip_Final.aep","stillImageLocation":"5","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"88","itemId":"94677","itemName":"NEON LIGHTS","thumbName":"NEONLIGHTS","dateAdded":"2017-04-28 10:06:23","renderTime":"45","tested":"1","projectPath":"O:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2017\/NEONLIGHTS-Joe\/NeonLights.aep","stillImageLocation":"2.53","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"89","itemId":"64305","itemName":"Engine (Loop)","thumbName":"ENGINE","dateAdded":"2017-05-15 11:37:07","renderTime":"60","tested":"1","projectPath":"O:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2017\/Engine-Scott\/Engine.aep","stillImageLocation":"4.67","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"90","itemId":"11287","itemName":"Energy Core","thumbName":"ENERGYCORE","dateAdded":"2017-05-22 13:08:40","renderTime":"30","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2017\/EnergyCore-Scott\/EnergyCore.aep","stillImageLocation":"6.73","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"91","itemId":"48745","itemName":"Football Helmet","thumbName":"FOOTBALLHELMET","dateAdded":"2017-07-03 16:09:42","renderTime":"120","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2017\/FootballHelmet-Scott\/FootballHelmet.aep","stillImageLocation":"7","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"92","itemId":"85515","itemName":"Light Shine","thumbName":"LIGHTSHINE","dateAdded":"2017-08-18 14:09:50","renderTime":"30","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2017\/LightShine-Scott\/LightShine.aep","stillImageLocation":"2","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"93","itemId":"61876","itemName":"Baseball Dirt","thumbName":"BASEBALLDIRT","dateAdded":"2017-08-31 10:31:22","renderTime":"40","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2017\/BaseballDirt-Scott\/BaseballDirt.aep","stillImageLocation":"7.27","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"94","itemId":"48066","itemName":"Spooky","thumbName":"SPOOKY","dateAdded":"2017-09-01 13:58:36","renderTime":"15","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2017\/Spooky-Jake\/Spooky.aep","stillImageLocation":"2","categoryArray":["Sports"],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"95","itemId":"33584","itemName":"Get Loud","thumbName":"GETLOUD","dateAdded":"2017-09-07 11:58:02","renderTime":"45","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2017\/GetLoud-Scott\/GetLoud.aep","stillImageLocation":"1.77","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"96","itemId":"21713","itemName":"STAR BURST","thumbName":"STARBURST","dateAdded":"2017-10-19 18:20:29","renderTime":"15","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2017\/StarBurst-Joe\/StarBurst.aep","stillImageLocation":"0","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"97","itemId":"76554","itemName":"Magic Twirl","thumbName":"MAGICFINAL","dateAdded":"2017-10-26 11:19:52","renderTime":"20","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2017\/Magic-Lillie\/Magic.aep","stillImageLocation":"825","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"98","itemId":"64452","itemName":"Sports Car","thumbName":"SPORTSCAR","dateAdded":"2017-10-27 10:26:32","renderTime":"60","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2017\/SportsCar-Scott\/SportsCar.aep","stillImageLocation":"14.77","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"99","itemId":"15074","itemName":"Ice Logo","thumbName":"ICELOGO","dateAdded":"2017-11-01 11:53:48","renderTime":"45","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2017\/IceLogo-Scott\/IceLogo.aep","stillImageLocation":"9.33","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":["LensFlare"]},{"id":"100","itemId":"95033","itemName":"Hot Air Balloon","thumbName":"BALLOON","dateAdded":"2017-11-02 08:10:22","renderTime":"10","tested":"1","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/CreativeEngine\/2017\/Balloon-Lillie\/Balloon.aep","stillImageLocation":"567","categoryArray":[],"keywordArray":[]},{"id":"243","itemId":"f0adeb21cfbfc7e1894debeef4cc6e22","itemName":"testingCrap","thumbName":"TESTINGCRAP","dateAdded":"2018-10-08 18:06:48","renderTime":"4","tested":"0","projectPath":"M:\/Projects\/Generics\/uploads\/testLocation","stillImageLocation":"0.13","categoryArray":["Sports","Holiday"],"keywordArray":["LensFlare"]}],
```

as you can see each template has an in the templateArray each object contains a categoryArray element like this `categoryArray: "sports, holidays"`

I also have a `filteredTemplateArray:[]`

```
selectedCategoriesArray:[],
    categories: ["Holiday","Sports","Misc","Automotive","Retail","Financial","Church","Community","Food"],
```

Heres the font end code for the checkbox

```
                          <div class="form-group">
                    <h5>Categories</h5>
                    <label v-for="category in categories">
                    <input v-model="selectedCategories" type="checkbox" :value="category" v-on:click="selectedCategory=category; selectCategory">
                    {{category}}
                    </label>

                </div>
```

lastly I have a computed property called selectCategory it looks like this

```
                  selectCategory: function(){
                      if(this.selectedCategories.length!=0){
                          var templateArray=this.templateArray;
                          for (var i=0; i<this.selectedCategories.length; i++){
                              console.log(i);
          return this.filteredTemplateArray=templateArray.filter((template)=>{
            return template.categoryArray.includes(this.selectedCategories[i]);


              })
}
  }
  }
```

I also am displaying the template info with this for loop

```
    <div v-cloak v-bind:key="template.itemId + '_' + index" v-for="(template, index) in selectCategory" class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
                <video muted :src="'mysource/'+template.itemId+'/'+template.thumbName+'.mp4'" controls preload="none" controlsList="nodownload nofullscreen" :poster="'mysource/'+template.itemId+'/'+template.thumbName+'.jpg'" loop="loop"></video>
                <div class="card-body">

                    <p class="card-title">{{template.itemName}}</p>
                    <!--end card-title-->
                    <p v-show="displayCount==0" class="card-text">Please create a display to customize</p>
                    <!--end user has no display card-text-->
                    <p v-show="displayCount>0" class="card-text">Custom Text, Custom Colors, Upload Logo</p>
                    <!--end user has display card text-->
                    <p class="card-text">{{template.renderTime}} minutes</p>
                    <a href="#" v-show="loggedIn==true && displayCount>0" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Customize</a>
                    <!--logged in and has display button-->
                    <a href="#" v-show="loggedIn==false" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" disabled>Customize</a>
                    <!--not logged in button-->
                    <a href="profile.php?showAddDisplayForm=1" v-show="loggedIn==true && displayCount==0" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Create A Display</a>
                </div>
                <!--end card-body-->
            </div>
            <!--end card-->
        </div>
```

everytime the user clicks on a category checkbox this function is run. Im trying to filter through the template array and find the items that contain the selected categories. however i always stops at 0 no matter what. When I add more than one item it does not work. I need away to get all the items that contain the selected categories and if selectedCategories is empty set filteredTemplateArray to the templateArray so all the items show up. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move the for loop lower in the method as shown. I also created a watcher that watches selectedCategories and when it changes run a method that filters out the duplicates and sets filtered categories back to the original array when the selectedCategories.length==0. This creates a category filter that counts up. for instance if sports and holidays are checked it will show only all items in sports and all items in holidays which seems to work better than counting down or showing the ones that only exist in both. I use app instead of this as its the variable i called my vue instance and because when you get deep into a function this does not always mean the app.

```
  watch: {
      selectedCategories(){
          this.categoryFilter();
      },
          sortBy(){
              this.sortTemplatesBy();
          }
    },
  methods: {
            sortTemplatesBy: function(){ 
      if(this.sortBy == "az") {
        this.filteredTemplateArray.sort(function(a,b) {
          if(a.itemName > b.itemName) {
            return 1;
          }
          if(a.itemName < b.itemName) {
            return -1;
          }
          return 0;
        });
      }

      if(this.sortBy == "dateAdded") {
        this.filteredTemplateArray.sort(function(a,b) {
          if(a.dateAdded < b.dateAdded) {
            return 1;
          }
          if(a.dateAdded > b.dateAdded) {
            return -1;
          }
          return 0;
        });
      }

      if(this.sortBy == "renderTime") {
        this.filteredTemplateArray.sort(function(a,b) {
          return parseInt(a.renderTime) - parseInt(b.renderTime);
        });
      }
    },
      categoryFilter: function(){
          if(app.selectedCategories.length!=0){
          app.filteredTemplateArray=[];
          var templateArray = app.templateArray;
          for(i=0; i<app.selectedCategories.length; i++){
              var filtered=templateArray.filter(function(template){
                  var currentCategory=app.selectedCategories[i];
                  console.log("this is current category"+currentCategory+"end currentCategory");
                  var returnValue=template.categoryArray.includes(currentCategory);
                  console.log("this is i"+i+"end i");
                  console.log("this is return value"+returnValue+"end return value");
                  return returnValue;
              });
              console.log(filtered);
              app.filteredTemplateArray=app.filteredTemplateArray.concat(filtered);

      }
          var uniqueArray=[];
          var allResultsArray=app.filteredTemplateArray;
          for(j=0; j<allResultsArray.length; j++){
              if(uniqueArray.indexOf(allResultsArray[j]) == -1){
                  uniqueArray.push(allResultsArray[j])
              }
          }
          app.filteredTemplateArray=uniqueArray;
      } else {app.filteredTemplateArray=app.templateArray;}
          this.sortTemplatesBy();
      }
  }
```